# Data passed as undefined from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making a file selection in the child component and once file is selected I want to pass the selected file to the parent component. I am not able to figure out how to do that. Please help out. If I try to get the print the value inside the onDocumentSelected(value) it comes out to be undefined.

Error message
*Property or method "value" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render*

Parent Component

```
<template>
  <v-form :model='agency'>
    <DocumentSelect 
       type="file"
       ref="file"
       :required="true"
       name="vue-file-input"
       @change="onDocumentSelected(value)"
    />
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
  import DocumentSelect from 'views/document-selection.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DocumentSelect
  },
  props: ['agency'],
  methods: {
    onDocumentSelected(value) {
      console.log(value); //undefined
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
  <div class="input-group input-group--select primary--text" :class="{'input-group--required': required, 'input-group--error': hasError, 'error--text': hasError}" >
     <div class="input-group__input">
       <input
          type="file"
          name="name"
          ref="file"
          @change="onDocumentSelected" />
     </div>
      <div class="input-group__details">
        <div class="input-group__messages input-group__error" v-for="error in errorBucket">
          {{error}}
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Validatable from  'vuetify/es5/mixins/validatable.js'

  export default {
    mixins: [Validatable],
    props: ['type', 'name', 'required'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        inputValue: ''
      };
    },
    watch: {
      inputValue: function(value) {
        this.validate();
        console.log(value); // *Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: input, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}*
        this.$emit('change', {value});
      },
    },
    methods: {
      onFileSelected(event) {
        this.inputValue = event
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your watch method and move the logic inside `onFileSelected`:

```
@change="onFileSelected($event)"
```

```
onFileSelected(e) {
  this.validate();
  this.$emit('document-selected', e);
}
```

Then, in the parent, listen for the `document-selected` event:

```
<DocumentSelect 
       type="file"
       ref="file"
       :required="true"
       name="vue-file-input"
       @document-selected="onDocumentSelected($event)"
/>
```

You then have access to that value to do what you want with.